# html element with height attribute 100% don't cover the whole window

Tags: html, css, footer

I want to have a footer at the bottem of my page.
I have followed a lot of different tutorials, but it won't work. 
when i scale my screen until there is a scrollbar the footer is at the bottem of the window and not at the end of the page.

this is my css:

```
 html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}
#footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 16%;
    margin-right: 16%;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 68%;
}
```

html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <body>
          <nav>
                ....
          </nav>
          <div id="content">
                ....
          </div>
          <div id="footer">
                ....
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Images:

[the footer at the bottem of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4zxz.jpg)

[when I scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTwvo.jpg)

Is there somebody who can help me?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML. `height: 100%` means that the element will be 100% of it's parent. By setting a height of 100% on your `html`, you may be setting the HTML height to the height of your window. Perhaps that's why an absolute position would be using the window position instead of the body. Again, cannot be sure without the HTML.

Comment: I've edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else, because your code works ok with that example. Are you using iframes? Please try to put a snippet

Also if you have an element with **`float`** positioning you should put a `<div style='clear:both`>`before the #footer div, floating elements could do a lot of weird things if you don't clear.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}
#footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 16%;
    margin-right: 16%;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 68%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="footer"> footer</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awesome way to stick a footer at the bottom of your page, without using height: 100%.

```css
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <header>header stuff!</header>
  <main class="Site-content">Main Content stuff</main>
  <footer>footer stuff!</footer>
</body>
```